# Custom post type's get_permalink returns wrong url

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting

Currently my permalink setting is `/paper/%postname%/`.

I am developing a plugin, so the following is done during the activation.

I am programatically adding a new custom-post-type called 'meta', like this (at 'init'):

```
register_post_type( POST_TYPE,
  array(
  'labels' => array('menu_name' => 'meta'),
  'public' => true,
  'rewrite' => array('with_front'=>false,'slug'=>'meta','pages'=>false)
  )
);
```

Then in the activation I programatically added a meta post, and use `get_permalink()`. But I get the following url:

`http://localhost/wordpress/paper/faq/`

This url leads to the 'not found' page. The correct url should be:

`http://localhost/wordpress/meta/faq/`

In the admin meta post edit page, the displayed permalink is the correct `http://localhost/wordpress/meta/faq`

I also tried to `flush_rewrite_rules();` before I call `get_permalink()`. But it didn't work.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Are you able to consistently reproduce this by creating more posts and getting wrong results from `get_permalink()`?

Answer (score 2):

At what stage are you registering your post type? If it's going right in the admin I'm thinking that you might be registering your post type too late. It has to be done on `init` to work...

Also, removing the `'pages'=>false` might just fix it.

Comment: yes it is done in init like `add_action('init', 'set_post_type_meta');`, NOT inside the activation function.
I tried removing it but it didn't work either.

Comment: @lulalala Try adding a `flush_rewrite_rules();` after registering your custom post type.