# Second get_permalink inside loop points to wrong URL

Tags: posts, loop, permalinks

For some reason the second **get_permalink** located on the featured image is pointing to the current page, instead of the post URL.

The first **get_permalink** works fine. They are both inside the same loop.

I've posted a trimmed down version of the loop below.

The full code for the loop in case it's helpful: 
https://jsfiddle.net/hemjegzy/

Any help is greatly appreciated.

### Loop Code (Trimmed)

```
    <?php
        if ( have_posts() ) :
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    ?>
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'post-single-no-sidebar' ); ?>>

        <?php if ( is_single() ) { ?> 
        <?php
            the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
        } else {
            the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h1>' );
        }
        ?>
            <a href="<?php get_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </a>

    </article>
   <?php
        endwhile;   
        endif;
   ?>
```

### Additional notes:

All plugins and versions of WordPress are up-to-date. I have checked any plugins may be the cause of the issue.

I've looked at answer to:

[WP get_permalink Return Wrong URL](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/265542/wp-get-permalink-return-wrong-url)

[Custom post type's get_permalink returns wrong url](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29784/custom-post-types-get-permalink-returns-wrong-url)

[Login to wp-admin "redirect_to" points to wrong URL after migration](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121084/login-to-wp-admin-redirect-to-points-to-wrong-url-after-migration)

I do not believe these are the same issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_permalink` doesn't output anything, it `return`s the permalink. Your first call works because you use it within `the_title`, which `echo`s its value along with any `before` and `after` parameters you pass to it.

Change your second instance to:

```
<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>
```

or use `the_permalink`, which `echo`s the value instead of `return`ing.

```
<?php the_permalink(); ?>
```

Many functions within WordPress follow this same pattern, `get_` vs. `the_`, one returns for use within php, one prints to page.

Comment: I thought it would be something simple, thank you.